# Getting parent record id as undefined in SF1

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, salesforce1-app, whatid, relatedlistnew

There is a custom obj, and i am trying to create a record from it's related list and it has aura component embedded with LWC. Now, I need to get the parent record id while creating a record from related list.
In aura I got the parent record id from the URL like below.

URL:
https://sabeunitycheck.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/Task/new?inContextOfRef=1.eyJ0eXBlIjoic3RhbmRhcmRfX3JlY29yZFJlbGF0aW9uc2hpcFBhZ2UiLCJhdHRyaWJ1dGVzIjp7InJlY29yZElkIjoiYTBBMdEFGFGfdgpTmFtZSI6Ik1DUE1fUHJlbWlzZV9fYyIsInJlbGF0aW9uc2hpcEFwaU5hbWUiOiJPcGVuQWN0aXZpdGllcyIsImFjdGlvbk5hbWUiOiJ2aWV3In0sInN0YXRlIjp7IndzIjoiL2xpZ2h0bmluZy9yL01DUE1fUHJlbWlzZV9fYy9hMEExcTAwMDAwOWVNQkRFQTIvdmlldz8wLnNvdXJjZT1hbG9oYUhlYWRlciJ9fQ%3D%3D&ws=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FMCPM_CustObj__c%2Fa0A1g000009eMDDEA2%2Fview%3F0.source%3DalohaHeader&count=2&0.source=alohaHeader

createTask.aura.js

({
doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
//close tab changes

```
    var whatid;

    var pageRef = component.get("v.pageReference");
    var state = pageRef.state; // state holds any query params
    var base64Context = state.inContextOfRef;
    var recid;
    if (base64Context && base64Context.startsWith("1\.")) {
         base64Context = base64Context.substring(2);
    
        var addressableContext = JSON.parse(window.atob(base64Context));

        recid = addressableContext.attributes.recordId;

    }
    alert('aura -recid==>' + recid);
    if(recid){
        component.set("v.whatid",recid);
    }
```

}
})

createTask.aura.html

<aura:component controller="createTaskcontrl" implements="lightning:hasPageReference,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:actionOverride,lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global" >

<aura:attribute name="whatid" type="String" />

<c:CreateTaskLwc whatid="{!v.whatid}"></c:mCPM_CreateTaskLwc>

</aura:component>

And trying to pass this id from aura to LWC

import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';

export default class CreateTaskLwc extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

//get the WhatId form the URL

```
@api whatid;
```

connectedCallback() {

console.log('this.whatid1==>' + this.whatid);

//what id coming in desktop, but getting undefined in SF1

}
I got the exact parent record id in desktop, but in SF1 I am getting undefined error for whatid.

Please help, how can I get the parent record id in LWC in SF1 ??

Comment: Was anyone able to get a resolution for this?